# How to handle chained promises in a loop in nodejs with bluebird

Tags: node.js, loops, promise, bluebird, chain

The gist of the problem is:

```
for (let i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
    AsyncCall_1({'someProperty': list[i] })
    .then((resp_1) => {
        resp_1.doSomething();
        resp_1.AsyncCall_2()
        .then((resp_2) => {
            resp_2.doSomething();
        })
  })
}

after last resp.AsyncCall_2.then(()=> {
//do something
})
```

I need to sequentially chain all the promises so that, the loop waits for the "resp.AsyncCall_2" function to be resolved for its next iteration. After last "resp.AsyncCall_2" call do something. (since all the promises will be resolved the)

Actual Problem:

```
for (var i=0;i<todo.assignTo.length;i++) {
    Users.findOne({'username': todo.assignTo[i] })
    .then((user) => {
         user.assigned.push(todo.title);
         user.notificationCount.assignedTodosCount++;
         user.save()
         .then((user) => {
             console.log("todo is assigned to the user: " + user.username)
         })
     })
}


//to something at last call resloved (I know this is wrong way of doing this)
Users.find({})
.then((users)=> {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i=0;i<users.length;i++) {
        users[i].notificationCount.totalTodosCount++;
        promises.push(users[i].save());
    }
    Promise.all(promises)
    .then(()=> {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        console.log("todo is successfully posted");
        res.json({success : true, todo});
    },(err) => next(err))
.catch((err) => next(err));
})
```

Thank You in Advance..

Comment: Given you're on node.js, nothing should stop you from just using `async`/`await` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In modern versions of node.js, you can just use `async/await` and don't need to use Bluebird iteration functions:

```
async function someMiddlewareFunc(req, res, next) {
    try {
        for (let item of list) {
            let resp_1 = await AsyncCall_1({'someProperty': item });
            resp_1.doSomething();
            let resp_2 = await resp_1.AsyncCall_2();
            resp_2.doSomething();
        }
        // then do something here after the last iteration 
        // of the loop and its async operations are done
        res.json(...);
    } catch(err) {
        next(err);
    }
}
```

This will serialize the operations (which is what you asked for) so the 2nd iteration of the loop doesn't start until the async operations in the first iteration is done.

---

But, it doesn't appear in your real code that you actually need to serialize the individual operations and serializing things that don't have to be serialized usually makes the end-to-end time to complete them be longer.  So, you could run all the items in your loop in parallel, collect all the results at the end and then send your response and Bluebird's `Promise.map()` would be quite useful for that because it combines a `.map()` and a `Promise.all()` into one function call:

```
function someMiddlewareFunc(req, res, next) {
    Promise.map(list, (item) => {
        return AsyncCall_1({'someProperty': item}).then(resp_1 => {
            resp_1.doSomething();
            return resp_1.AsyncCall_2();
        }).then(resp_2 => {
            return resp_2.doSomething();
        });
    }).then(results => {
        // all done here
        res.json(...);
    }).catch(err => {
        next(err);
    });
}
```

---

FYI, when using `res.json(...)`, you don't need to set these        `res.statusCode = 200;` or `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');` as they will be done for you automatically.

---

Further notes about Bluebird's `Promise.map()`.  It accepts a `{concurrency: n}` option that tells Bluebird how many operations are allowed to be "in flight" at the same time.  By default, it runs them all in parallel at the same time, but you can pass any number you want as the concurrency option.  If you pass `1`, it will serialize things.  Using this option can be particularly useful when parallel operation is permitted, but the array is very large and iterating all of them in parallel runs into either memory usage problems or overwhelms the target server. In that case, you can set the `concurrency` value to some intermediate value that still gives you some measure of parallel execution, but doesn't overwhelm the target (some number between 5 and 20 is often appropriate - it depends upon the target service).  Sometimes, commercial services (like Google) also have limits about how many requests they will handle at the same time from the same IP address (to protect them from one account using too much of the service at once) and the `concurrency` value can be useful for that reason too.

Comment: @AshwaniKumarKashyap - Can you help me understand what changed to cause you to remove the accepted answer designation on this question 2 years later?  What is this answer missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`Promise.each`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html)?

```
const users = todo.assignTo.map(function(user) {
   return Users.findOne({'username': assigned_to });        
}
Promise.each(users, function(user) {
   user.assigned.push(todo.title);
   user.notificationCount.assignedTodosCount++;
   user.save()
   .then((user) => {
      console.log("todo is assigned to the user: " + user.username)
   })
}
```